# Is it possible to use Visual Studio Code as your exclusive IDE when working with Websphere Commerce?

Tags: server, ide, visual-studio-code, websphere, ibm-rad

Can I use VSCode to start/stop the server, view live logging, debug with breakpoints, and modify code?  Or are you stuck with RAD/Intellij as your only ways to work with Websphere Commerce?